# Incorrect behavior of events dispatcher with mouse

Tags: multithreading, qt, events, resize, mouse

I have DLL which attaches to non-QT application. In DLL I create QThread and QApplication instances and run event loop. And I have QDialog and QTimer for hiding dialog after 4 sec.
Also I have overridden mousePressEvent but it's didn't work properly. Overridden function is called only when I resize dialog. If I don't do resizing, dialog is hiding and mousePressEvent function didn't call.

Thread:

```
void MThread::run()
{
  MThread::_app = new QApplication(_argc, _argv);
  _main_window = new SongTitle();
  _main_window->SetTitle(QString::fromLocal8Bit("lalala"));
  _main_window->ShowTitle();
  MThread::_app->exec();
}
```

Mouse event:

```
void SongTitle::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
  MessageBoxW(0, L"in mouse event",L"",0);
  switch (event->button()){
    case Qt::LeftButton:
      MessageBoxW(0, L"left",L"",0);
      break;
    case Qt::RightButton:
      MessageBoxW(0, L"right",L"",0);
      break;
    default:
      QDialog::mousePressEvent(event);
      break;
    }
}
```

How to fix this behavior?

Comment: To clarify your question: you want to receive mouse events without any Qt window visible on screen ?

Comment: I want to receive events' immediately after actions. Don't know why events dispatcher freezes and doesn't handle mouse events.

Comment: If SongTitle is your dialog, and if it is hidden, you can't receive mouse events with Qt. Qt only receives and dispatches mouse events to the active window if that window is a Qt window.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overriding the mouse release event, not the press event. Also there's no reason to use windows APIs like `MessageBox` when you've got Qt equivalents like `QMessageBox`.

Most likely you miss the fact that a widget will only get the events that haven't been used up by other widgets that are on top of it. Your `SongTitle` dialog likely has child widgets, and you are clicking on those widgets, not on `SongTitle` itself.

If you want to get mouse events as they come to all of widget's children, you can install an event filter on all child widgets. That event filter will receive all events as they come in.